# Is there any way to validate token before execution of rest api using spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, spring-boot

I have configured spring boot for rest controller.
I created many api but i need to validate my token information in every api at begging, Is user is authorized or not base on provided token.

During the signin i am generating token that token required in every api for accessing information. if token is not valid then i need to return message `Sorry, your provided token information has been expired or not exists.`

below is the my api.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/delete", method= RequestMethod.DELETE)
public Map<String, Object> delete(@RequestBody String reqData,HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String, Object> m1 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(reqData);
    Token token= tokenDao.getByTokenCode(jsonData.getString("token"));
    if(token==null){
        m1.put("status", "error");
        m1.put("message", "Sorry, your provided token information expired or not exists.");
        return m1;
    }
    //here my logic to remove user from database.
}
```

Is there any way to check token functionality in service method or using annotation, so i need to remove that same code in every api and need to use one common functionality.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use **HandlerInterceptor** to handle you token.

**HandlerInterceptor.preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)** will execute before any RequestMapping.

validate you token in **preHandle**.if token is valid continue,else throw exception,controller advice will handler the rest.

expose bean class of MappedInterceptor,spring will auto load HandlerInterceptor bean contains.

**ControllerAdvice** and **ExceptionHandler** can catch exception and return error message

**full example**

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class App {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "hello world";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    public static class MyException extends RuntimeException {

    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public MappedInterceptor getMappedInterceptor(MyHandlerInterceptor myHandlerInterceptor) {
        return new MappedInterceptor(new String[] { "/" }, myHandlerInterceptor);
    }

    @Component
    public static class TestBean {
        public boolean judgeToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String token = request.getParameter("token");
            if (token == null) {
                throw new MyException();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Component
    public static class MyHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

        @Autowired
        TestBean testBean;

        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
                throws Exception {
            return testBean.judgeToken(request);
        }

        @Override
        public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
                ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
                Exception ex) throws Exception {

        }
    }

    @ControllerAdvice
    public static class MyExceptionHandler {
        @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
        @ResponseBody
        public Map<String, Object> handelr() {
            Map<String, Object> m1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            m1.put("status", "error");
            m1.put("message", "Sorry, your provided token information expired or not exists.");
            return m1;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Great man it;s worked for me, but is there any way to  check for selected api,  because some of the api have access without token.

Comment: you can set includePatterns and excludePatterns for MappedInterceptor.those patterns will filter request mapping for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TokenVallidation
 {        
    public static boolean tokenValidation(user id, String token){    
        Token token= tokenDao.getByTokenCode(id,jsonData.getString("token"));
        if(token==null){
            m1.put("status", "error");
            m1.put("message", "Sorry, your provided token information expired or not exists.");
            return false;
        }     
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

for controller pass user id and token and check the token. you need to update `dao` method as per `user id` parameter.

Comment: Can I extend or used as a annotation your proveded class?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting token from database and matching with current token you can use **cache**. create your own cache object like `Map` or a static `string`, which will have the latest token. and you can direct compare incoming token with this token from cache. no need to hit database for every time.

Comment: I am new in Spring, here i am generating new token for each users. so we need to validate that in every api. is the client side application provided token is valid or not?

Comment: token should be validated in server side only. you can not share your validation code to client side.

Comment: i am doing same validating in every api, but i need create separate method for that and use in every api. that method automatically check token status and if valid then execute api code otherwise return message from common method directly.

Comment: so want to write another method for all user and apis right?

Comment: yes, i need to crate one common method/service/annotation that can check first before api code execution.

Comment: ohhh okay..you can use Interceptor, filter or @ModelAttribute

Comment: I am new in spring can you please guide me, how can I used interceptor or filters in my provided code?

Comment: look into this. you will get the idea. http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptors-example-handlerinterceptor-and-handlerinterceptoradapter